# What to implement for fixed (or something like that) navigation without the header if I have 1 up to 3 links?

Tags: mobile, navigation, web, material-design

I have a following web app (important parts translated manually, it's in Russian originally):

[image]

How can I decompose or remove the top bar navigation?

The problem is in the following:

Some of navigation fields are unavailable from time to time. I do not like the idea of that "dynamic" menu - it's not very obvious for users and also overloads

- I would prefer to place search box over there.

Also in case when only one page is available it means that it is also active and menu becomes useless.

All application visual content (except some popups and so on) is that cards (Shant Rock, Indie People, Rock etc...).

They are placed in 3 sections - recommendations, favorites and top. Depending on conditions only top100 (before the auth), or top100 and favorites( if recommendations are unavailable), or top100 and recommendations (if nothing is in favorites yet) would be shown.

All parts of content are expected to be important and be available all the time.

I really do not know what to do with that navigation without hiding it in hamburger drawer.

Comment: I would assume the top 100 would always be available?

Comment: From the explanation, I get that you search for an alternative design for the top-row navigation. The question asks for advice on implementation, though. You'll get better answers (and less implementations, which are not really this site's content) if you change the question.

Comment: What does the current hamburger menu look like when it is in its expanded state?

Comment: To add to Julia's question. Do you have any data showing how many people do use the 3 items in the top nav today?

Comment: if they're dependent on what view you're on why not just place them in part of the view instead of in a header/menu?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would add a search icon to the navigation and remove the tabs, then I would add the tabs into the search page and call them categories. This should allow you to not have a dynamic navigation bar and still have the sections easily accessible. Then in the navigation bar you can put the title of the active section so that the user doesn't lose track while navigating. I made a quick mock-up to show you what I mean. http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/PNjava/